# Pandas: Operations on rows taking into account previous row in a dataframe

Tags: pandas, performance, dataframe

I have a big dataframe (100 columns x 200 000 rows). I want to go through the dataframe row-by-row and update the row N content depending on row N-1 content. Currently I proceed like this (the conditions are actually a bit more complicated and I apply the same logic about 10 times per row on different group of columns):

```
for index in df.index:
                   if df['A'][index] < df['B'][index] and df['C'][index-1] == 0:
                        df['D'][index] = df['A'][index]
                        df['E'][index] = df['F'][index-1]
```

I would like to know if there is a way to do this way faster. Should I use other objects than dataframes such as numpy objects?
I guess there is a better way to do this because functions like "rolling" does the same kind of logic and runs in less than 1 second for the whole dataframe.

Thanks for your help guys!

Comment: Yo can check out the `.shift()` function in pandas. It helps you compare with other rows

Comment: Is pandas optimal at these sizes? Have you considered Spark as an alternative, for instance? There you could use the window function `lag`: https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/content/spark-sql-functions-windows.html#lag